# How to convert this curl request to Http post request for file upload in java?

Tags: java, rest, curl

Following is my curl request:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'data1@/Users/Documents/file.csv' http://localhost:8000/predict
```

Following is my equivalent Java implementation.

```
String filePath = inputFilePath;
        String url = inputUrl;
        File file = new File(filePath);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost(inputUrl);
        uploadFile.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(inputFilePath));

        HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .addPart("data1", fileBody)
                .build();


        uploadFile.setEntity(reqEntity);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am trying to invoke my R Rest API endpoint from my Java HTTP post.

```
#* @post /predict
mypredict <- function(data1) {
  print(data1)

}
```

(1) Is my equivalent Java HTTP Post request correct?
(2) I am able to invoke the R rest endpoint using my curl command. But for some reason when i sent the POST request through my Java code, i see that data1 is not being passed as part of post request. I see this error in R.

```
<simpleError in print(data1): argument "data1" is missing, with no default>
```

I feel my Java equivalent curl implementation is wrong. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (as curl does for this case) but supply an actual body (entity) that corresponds to `multipart/form-data` which is radically different. Instead **use `URLEncodedFormEntity`** containing (for your case) one `NameValuePair` something like this:

```
byte[] contents = Files.readAllBytes (new File(filepath).toPath());
List<BasicNameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data1", new String(contents,charset));
uploadFile.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity (list));
```

And you don't need `addHeader("content-type",...)` because setting the entity automatically supplies the content-type header (and content-length).